# Is any natural number a part of fractional part of Pi?

Tags: pi, natural-numbers

Is any natural number a part of fractional part of Pi? For example, 14 is a part of 3.1415...
How to count this part occurancies in Pi fractional part?

Comment: You should learn and use MathJax (LaTeX) to format your posts. It is also far from clear what you mean by "count this part occurancies". I believe the answer to your first question is: "Most (all?) mathematicians believe $\pi$ is normal (the technical term for what you're asking about), but it's not proven."

Answer (score 2):

Nobody knows. It is possible that [$\pi$ is normal](https://www.atractor.pt/mat/fromPI/pinormal-_en.html), and this will imply that every digit will appear in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ about once in every $10$ digits, that every pair of digits will appear in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ about once in every $100$ digits and so on. But that has not been proved.